# Event handler for clickable image

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have this function which gets executed when a link is clicked.
But there seems to be an issue with that. When I use some text for the same link.

The function seems to get executed well, but except when I place an image in the same place,
then event handler function doesn't seem to be working.

I created a Fiddle for this one: http://jsfiddle.net/bkvirendra/5QqUB/

When the link is clicked a ul list is shown. And when the user clicks anywhere instead of the link the ul list gets disappeared.
So when I place an image instead of the text its doesn't seem to be working!
How can I show the same ul list when the image is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because when you click the image, the event target becomes the `img` tag, not the `a` tag.

Try this:

```
$(".item").hide();
$("#a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".item").show();
});

$(document).click(function() {
    $(".item").hide();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5QqUB/1/)

You should also consider removing the `$(".item").hide()` line and using `display: none` in CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `e.target` return the clicked element, so it's returning the image. Try this code:

```
$("html").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target == document.getElementById("a") || e.target.nodeName=='IMG') {
        $(".item").show();
        //alert(1);
    } else {
        $(".item").hide();
        //alert(2);
    }
});​
```